# Customize the Sonata Admin Dashboard - Sonata and Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I've followed this tutorial, and made it work : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html.
My Admin Class is displaying well, everything is working for the moment, that's fine.
I've also added a custom logo on top.

Now, I'd just want to customize the dashboard.
For example, I have a my "Station" entity displayed. 
To add an entry to this entity, the link has for name "link_add".
Same for the list : "link_list". And so on, "label_filters", "link_action_create", ... 
Everything is like this. I guess this is the standard names for this actions into the default layout. But it's not very "sexy", even for a demo.

How can I change these names ? I can't figure out which file I have to edit ? Or even what I should do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check your config.yml if

```
framework:
    translator:      ~
```

is defined or not.

Comment: Hello. No it's not, it's actually commented. The translator line is actually commented like this : #translator: { fallback: %locale% }        Should I decomment it ? I'll try.

Comment: Ok, it worked ! I guess I can change the locale env into the parameters.yml file. Thanks.